# The role of PIDA in C-H activation reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

PIDA ((Diacetoxyiodo)benzene) is a hypervalent iodine(III) compound that acts an attractive oxidizing agent in most of the transition metal catalyzed reactions. Can someone explain me the mechanism of PIDA in the hydroxilation of C-H bonds?

Comment: Do you have an example of the reaction you’re interested in? The mechanisms of these processes aren’t always well understood and often highly context dependent

Comment: "most of the transition metal catalyzed reactions" Really? *Most* of what group of reactions? It certainly isn't most C-H activation reactions.